# How do you fix the Gatbsy concurrent download error

Tags: gatsby, headless

I am running Gatsby develop on windows, I keep getting this error messages:

```
some.jpg is taking a long time time (longer than 15 seconds).

Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rename

Try lowering process.env.GATSBY_CONCURRENT_DOWNLOAD.
It's currently set to undefined
```

I have changed the GATSBY_CONCURRENT_DOWNLOAD in my .env file, but still not working. Any ideas why it's running fine on a colleagues MAC, but not for me?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running it in the Node command?

```
GATSBY_CONCURRENT_DOWNLOAD=15 gatsby develop
```

Or:

```
GATSBY_CONCURRENT_DOWNLOAD=15 gatsby build
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @Ferran but not sure i can run that command:
The term 'GATSBY_CONCURRENT_DOWNLOAD=15' is not
recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Comment: How are you trying to run now? You should update the `package.json` commands

Comment: thanks, I added it to package.json ("scripts": {"develop": "GATSBY_CONCURRENT_DOWNLOAD=15 gatsby develop"... but getting the same error messages. Tried lowering to 1 and same thing

Comment: @jkthompson83 I know it's been a while but did you ever find a solution to this? Running into it myself now.

Comment: @AllanKiezel - sorry, i didnt find a solution, then moved away from using Gatsby!

Answer (score -1):

You have to add it to your .env.production or .`env.development` file in a new line.

```
GATSBY_CONCURRENT_DOWNLOAD=15
```